# Glassfish: The thread pool's task queue is full

Tags: java, glassfish

In glassfish 4.1 i have the following error:

```
[2016-08-24T04:00:45.586+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []     [org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-1-kernel(1) SelectorRunner] [timeMillis: 1472004045586] [levelValue: 1000] [[
doSelect exception
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: The thread pool's task queue is full, limit: 4096
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool.onTaskQueueOverflow(AbstractThreadPool.java:490)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.QueueLimitedThreadPool.execute(QueueLimitedThreadPool.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.GrizzlyExecutorService.execute(GrizzlyExecutorService.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

do u know which it's the possible problem?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21246) in the Glassfish's official Jira. It affects the same version as you have (it was created for version 4.1_b10, but is actual for 4.1.1 too) and was not solved yet. You may post your exception's artifacts as a comment to this issue, to help solve this problem.

The only solution provided (but not recommended though), is to configure the server's `http-thread-pool`, to make it unlimited by changing the `max-queue-size` size value to -1, as

```
<thread-pools>
    ...
    <thread-pool name="http-thread-pool" max-queue-size="-1"></thread-pool>
    ...
</thread-pools>
```

But for sure, this may cause some other issues, since it may run out of the maximum available resources.